# Cannot validate aggregate of collection field value

Tags: php, symfony, validation

A receipt entity contains a collection of tickets. Each ticket has an `$amount` property. It is not yet possible to constrain the sum of ticket amounts to be greater than or equal to 0.

Note that a receipt is initially created without any tickets. Tickets are then added/edited in a given receipt by a `TicketController` in a javascript dialog box.

Through debug I've found that the `Constraint` is called but not the `ConstraintValidator`

Based on the accepted answer to this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621225/pass-custom-parameters-to-custom-validationconstraint-in-symfony2) I have:

#### Edit controller:

```
    public function editTicketAction(Request $request, ReceiptTotal $rcptTotal, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $ticket = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
        $receipt = $ticket->getReceipt();
        $total = $rcptTotal->getReceiptTotal($receipt);
        $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket,
            [
                'validation_groups' => ['edit'],
                'cancel_action' => $this->generateUrl('homepage'),
                'rcptTotal' => $total,
        ]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
...
    }
```

Where `$total = $rcptTotal->getReceiptTotal($receipt);` provides the current total of tickets via a service.

#### Form builder includes:

```
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\NonNegative;
...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
...
        $form->add(
            'amount', TextType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Amount',
                'label_attr' => ['style' => 'color: red;'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NonNegative(['rcptTotal' => $options['rcptTotal']])
                ]
                ]
        );
```

#### Constraint & Validator:

```
class NonNegative extends Constraint
{
    protected $rcptTotal;

    public function __construct($options)
    {
        $this->rcptTotal = $options['rcptTotal'];
    }

    public $message = 'Receipt total may not be less than zero';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this) . 'Validator';
    }

    public function getRcptTotal()
    {
        return $this->rcptTotal();
    }

}


class NonNegativeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function validate($amount, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $total = $contraint->getRcptTotal() + $amount;

        if ($total < 0) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is related to your problem but you have a typo in your `NonNegativeValidator` class, in the `validate` function : `$constraint` not `$contraint`.

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eye! It didn't make a difference though. If the validator had been run PHP would have complained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a combination of entity validation callbacks plus a ticket property. The property is `$rcptTotal`, which is set to the total of ticket amounts for a given receipt.

#### TicketType form modifications:

```
->add(
    'amount', TextType::class,
    [
        'label' => 'Amount',
        'label_attr' => ['style' => 'color: red;'],
    ]
)
->add('rcptTotal', HiddenType::class, [
    'data' => $options['rcptTotal'],
    ])
...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Ticket::class,
            'validation_groups' => [],
            'required' => false,
            'rcptTotal' => null,
        ));
    }
```

#### Ticket entity additions:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(groups={"edit"})
 */
public function validateEdit(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $receipt = $this->getReceipt();
    $total = 0;
    $tickets = $receipt->getTickets();
    foreach ($tickets as $value) {
        $total += ($this->getId() !== $value->getId()) ? $value->getAmount() : $this->getAmount();
    }
    if (0 > $total) {
        $context->buildViolation('Receipt total may not be < 0!')
            ->atPath('amount')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}

/**
 * @Assert\Callback(groups={"add"})
 */
public function validateAdd(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    $total = $this->getRcptTotal();
    if (0 > $total + $this->getAmount()) {
        $context->buildViolation('Receipt total may not be < 0!')
            ->atPath('amount')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}

private $rcptTotal;

public function setRcptTotal($rcptTotal)
{
    $this->rcptTotal = $rcptTotal;
}

public function getRcptTotal()
{
    return $this->rcptTotal;
}
```

#### Ticket controller modifications:

```
public function addTicketAction(Request $request, TicketArtist $owner, ReceiptTotal $rcptTotal, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $receipt = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Receipt')->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    $total = $rcptTotal->getReceiptTotal($receipt);
    $ticket = new Ticket();
    $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket,
        [
            'validation_groups' => ['add'],
            'cancel_action' => $this->generateUrl('homepage'),
            'rcptTotal' => $total,
    ]);
...
}


public function editTicketAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ticket = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Ticket')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket,
        [
            'validation_groups' => ['edit'],
            'cancel_action' => $this->generateUrl('homepage'),
    ]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
...
}
```